# how to access container view child from parent view in swift

Tags: swift2

I have a parent viewController and it contain container view, which has a embedded viewController and from embedded view controller it has  four custom view controller(with segue).I need to access child viewController of container view  from parent what need to do ? in swift .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use delegate method and access the value from parent view controller. Hope this Help...